# What is the best fit data structure to work with Sets in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Assume I need to compare multiple sets and find which are equals or not.

In the end, I need to compare multiple sets and create a final set,
with unique data taken from each set. Also I need to handle all items 
which are repeating in different sets.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeating in different sets"? **(1)** A set may contain duplicates, or **(2)** A set may not contain duplicates, but items may be present in multiple sets.

Comment: The "best" collection to use is completely contextual.  Sometimes `List` is best, sometimes `HashSet`, sometimes `Dictionary`.  Learn the differences between them and decide which is best for this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`

You can create it like:

`var hashSet = new HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`

and then use methods to compare:

`hashSet.SetEquals(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will return true if hashSet and list contains same items

`hashSet.Overlaps(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will return true if hashSet contains one of the items from list

`hashSet.IsSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will return true if hashSet is subset of the list (order don't matter)

`hashSet.IsProperSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> list)` - same as `IsSubsetOf` but order matter

`hashSet.IsSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will return true if hashSet is superset of the list (order don't matter)

`hashSet.IsProperSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T> list)` - same as `IsSupersetOf` but order matter

Also there is methods to modify:

`hashSet.UnionWith(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will modify hashSet to contain elements which are exists 
in current hashSet or list or in both.

`hashSet.symmetricExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will modify hashSet to contain elements which are only exists 
in current hashSet or list but not in both.

`hashSet.IntersectWith(IEnumerable<T> list)` - will modify hashSet to contain elements which are exists 
in current hashSet and list.

For more information about `HashSet` see [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb359438) class, which represents a set of elements with no duplicates, and exposes methods like `IntersectWith`, `UnionWith`, `ExceptWith` etc. for common set operations